# Draw a frame in a custom ImageView on Android

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-imageview

I'm extending the ImageView class and overriding the onDraw method.
This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

- MyImageView has a black corner (frame with some padding);
- Inside this frame a bitmap is drawn;
- The frame must be fixed size, the inside bitmap can be scaled with ScaleGestureListener;

I don't want to create a frame by defining an XML Shape and set it as the background. The frame should be created inside the onDraw method.

From what I've understood from the documentation, the onDraw method gives you a canvas where there's a backing bitmap attached to the ImageView. The backing bitmap is where I draw by calling the draw...() methods on the canvas object.

To achieve my goal, I should draw a fixed size rectangle by using a Paint object and call drawRect(). This creates the frame and it works.

Given that I am succesfully able to scale the bitmap inside the frame, I don't understand how to draw the inside bitmap with padding and scale that bitmap.

I am thinking of two canvas. What should I do in my onDraw method?

```
public class ViewFinder extends ImageView {

    private Paint pnt;
    private Bitmap frameBmp;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public ViewFinder(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public ViewFinder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ViewFinder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        frameBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        pnt = new Paint();
        pnt.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pnt.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        pnt.setStrokeWidth(10.f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), pnt);
        canvas.drawBitmap(frameBmp, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        if(getDrawable() != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            System.out.println("scale!");
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I solved the problem, I'll leave this here in case somebody needs it.
When you draw onto a Canvas, you're basically customizing the draw behaviour before actually "print" something (a circle, a rectangle, another bitmap) on the canvas' backing bitmap handled by Android framework (canvas is given to you by onDraw). The canvas is the interface that you customize before telling it to draw something. The main point is that when you draw, you're going to *fill* the backing bitmap area. So, if you want to draw a frame around something, you basically have two options:

1. You can tell the canvas that you're going to clip the drawing area: in this case you use clipRect(). From now on, every drawing will be applied to the clipped area.
2. Print anything you want by calling one of the draw...() methods. Then, if you want to apply the frame, simply "overdraw" it with a drawRect: so the call order will be drawBitmap() first and drawRect() after. In this way, you fill the backing bitmap with your bitmap. Then you draw on the edges of your bitmap by calling drawRect().

The code above is incorrect: I'll rewrite the onDraw() method by using the 2nd option:

```
Bitmap bmp = ... //this is the bitmap we want to draw

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10.f);

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (getDrawable() == null) {
            return;
        }
        /* canvas already has a backing bitmap. 
        We're going to save the state of the canvas as 
        it will be altered with translations, rotation, 
        other drawings or whatever. */
        canvas.save();
        // Let's draw another bitmap onto the backing bitmap.
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
        ... apply other drawings or transformations ...
        // Now we need to restore our canvas. This will reset our customizations on the canvas.
        canvas.restore();
        // Finally, we draw our outer frame. 
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), pnt);

    }
```

Comment: what is frameBmp?  it always an empty Bitmap

Comment: You're right. I'm actually thinking that I need two Canvas. The first one, given by onDraw, has a backing bitmap that has the same size as the ImageView. There I drawRect the frame. Then, I need another canvas with smaller size of the original backing bitmap, and draw the bitmap that will be scaled inside that canvas. I don't know how to write the second goal.

Comment: So I'm having problem on how to draw two canvas in my view.

Comment: just set a padding to your ImageView and your Bitmap will be drawn inside it, so in onDraw method first draw the frame and then call super.onDraw, no need for two Canvases at all

Comment: If I call super.onDraw it actually set the padding. However, I'm not able to scale the canvas after calling super.onDraw().

Comment: why do you want to scale it?

Comment: @pskink I repeat, I think the way to go should be this (correct me if I'm wrong). I use the Canvas given by onDraw to drawRect my frame. Then, I need another Canvas canvas2 where the backingbitmap2 has more little width/height. So, when I drawBitmap inside backingbitmap2, it actually has padding. Also, I'm able to scale canvas2. Correct? Now, I don't know how to place canvas2 inside my ImageView.

Comment: there is no such thing like canvas2, View or ImageView has one canvas to draw onto

Comment: this is how it works: http://pastebin.com/cEyCjpsq

Comment: Ok, so I need padding and I need to scale the inner bitmap keeping the padding.

Comment: see the above pastebin

Comment: did it work? is it what you want?

Comment: @pskink Your comment were really useful, but that wasn't what I wanted. I solved by using canvas.clipRect(). When you call clipRect(), all the other drawings will apply to the clipped rect.